# Call function in another AWS lambda using existing call

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda

Please refer the code snippet below:

```py
    import awsgi
    import json
    from flask import (
    Flask,
    jsonify,
    request
    )

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
       return jsonify(status=200, message='OK')

    @app.route('/tester')
    def tst():

      rule = request.url_rule
      if 'tester' in  rule.rule:
         return {'status':200, 'message':'test'}

    def lambda_handler(event, context):    

    test = (awsgi.response(app, event, context))
    for key, value in test.items():
        if key == 'message':
            call = value

    return {
        'body': json.dumps(test)
    }
```

Now in call variable we have value 'test'.
This 'test' is also the name of a method in another lambda that I want to call.
can someone please help me with this
Thanking You

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to call an AWS Lambda function via the `invoke()` method? Every Lambda function has only one entry point, but you can pass information to the function via the `event`, so the function can look at the contents of `event` and then perform conditional logic (eg run a particular method defined in the code).

Comment: I have another lambda which has method test(event, context) and i want to call or invoke this function

Answer (score 0):

Each AWS Lambda function has one entry point via the function defined as the **Handler**.

When the AWS Lambda function is invoked, the Handler function is called. It is not possible to 'call' another function when invoking the Lambda function.

However, you could **add some logic to the Handler function** that examines the incoming `event` and checks for a test situation. The Handler function could then call the `test()` function. For example, add an entry to the `event` that says `"Test": "true"`, then have the Handler function check for this entry and, if present, call `test()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you you simply would like to call another lambda.

If thats what you are looking for, here is how you can do it.

```
import json
import boto3
from flask import (
  Flask,
  jsonify,
  request
)
import awsgi
client = boto3.client('lambda')


def lambda_handler(event, context):    

  test = 'other-function-name'
  response = client.invoke(
      FunctionName=test,
      InvocationType='RequestResponse',
      Payload=json.dumps({})
  )

  return {
      ...
      'body': json.dumps(response)
      ....
  }
```

If you don't like to wait for the other lambda to finish, you can use `InvocationType='RequestResponse'`

hope this helps.